# Replace NaN values with specific value per column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing values as well as some NaN. Now I have the mean of the columns and I want to insert the mean of the particular column into the NaN values. For eg:

[ColA and ColB have NaN to be replaced with the value of mean I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAr2p.png)

I have the mean for ColA and ColB. I want to insert them into the NaN locations. I could do that individually using the replace method. But for many columns, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research, read the docs?

Comment: Yes, I tried using 'replace'. But that works for a single column at a time. I want to apply this for multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: You’re doing to have to do multiple operations _anyway_, since according to your own post each column will be filled by the mean of that particular column.

Comment: @HrishikeshMahajan - then check my answer, it not working?

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15924.

Comment: @jezrael It did not work.

Comment: @HrishikeshMahajan - All columns are numeric?

Comment: @HrishikeshMahajan Also can you check `print (df.mean())` ?

Comment: I think @AlexanderCécile has a point. Since I have the mean of each column with me, I could do that sequentially but suppose the number of such columns is large. I was just hoping that the community could have a workaround to solve this problem.

Comment: @jezrael Yes. All are numeric and I have the mean with me already. I do not wish to calculate it again. Since that would be inaccurate.

Comment: @HrishikeshMahajan - Answer was edited.

Comment: No. I don't wish to calculate and then insert the mean. I also researched about that, which could be achieved using imputer. I already have the values for each column with me. I just wish to insert the mean value I posses of ColA into the NaN and similarly for other columns

Comment: @HrishikeshMahajan You need to be more specific. You can’t just throw out these words like “sequentially” with no explanation or precision, when there are probably a million different ways they can be interpreted here.

Comment: @HrishikeshMahajan - I think you can check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and change answer, also [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), better is change some data from my answer like you need

Comment: @jezrael The edit worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

If already has Series with means only use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,np.nan,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,np.nan,1,0],
         'E':[np.nan,3,6,np.nan,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

means = pd.Series([10,20], index=['B','E'])

df= df.fillna(means)
print (df)
   A     B  C    D     E  F
0  a   4.0  7  1.0  20.0  a
1  b  10.0  8  3.0   3.0  a
2  c   4.0  9  5.0   6.0  a
3  d   5.0  4  NaN  20.0  b
4  e   5.0  2  1.0   2.0  b
5  f   4.0  3  0.0   4.0  b
```

If need replace missing values in all numeric columns use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `mean` - it working because `mean` exclude non numeric columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,np.nan,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,np.nan,1,0],
         'E':[np.nan,3,6,np.nan,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df1 = df.fillna(df.mean())
print (df1)
   A    B  C    D     E  F
0  a  4.0  7  1.0  3.75  a
1  b  4.4  8  3.0  3.00  a
2  c  4.0  9  5.0  6.00  a
3  d  5.0  4  2.0  3.75  b
4  e  5.0  2  1.0  2.00  b
5  f  4.0  3  0.0  4.00  b
```

If need specify columns for means only change solution with list of columns names:

```
cols = ['D','B']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].mean())
print (df)
   A    B  C    D    E  F
0  a  4.0  7  1.0  NaN  a
1  b  4.4  8  3.0  3.0  a
2  c  4.0  9  5.0  6.0  a
3  d  5.0  4  2.0  NaN  b
4  e  5.0  2  1.0  2.0  b
5  f  4.0  3  0.0  4.0  b
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! But the mean of the columns are different and I have the values of them with me. I just want to substitute them with the values with me.

Answer (score 0):

try this, for those column which you want to fill.

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].fillna((df['column1'].mean()))
```