# How can I replace nan values from filtered multiple columns on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

I want to clean NaN values at my data frame separately. I used some filters for finding the NaN values. But same filter detected that another column include NaN values. This condition is confused my mind. I tried a lot of methods but these NaN values don't change.

Firstly see my dataframe;

[Raw DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FojNP.png)

[When the applied filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z4eg.png)

```
pop[(pop['Log GDP per capita'].isna())][(pop['Country name'])=='Somalia']
```

I used a lot of methods, but I can't change anything.

```
# Method 1
pop[(pop['Log GDP per capita']).isna()]['Log GDP per capita'].fillna(8,inplace=True)
# Method 2
pop['Log GDP per capita'] = pop['Log GDP per capita'].replace(np.nan,8,inplace=True)
# Method 3
pop[(pop['Log GDP per capita'].isna())][(pop['Country name'])=='Somalia']['Log GDP per capita'].replace(np.nan,7.6,inplace=True)
# Method 4
pop[(pop['Log GDP per capita'].isna())][(pop['Country name'])=='Somalia'].mask(pop['Log GDP per capita']=='', 7.946, inplace=True)
# Method 5
pop[(pop['Log GDP per capita'].isna())][(pop['Country name'])=='Somalia'].mask(pop['Log GDP per capita']==pd.np.nan, 7.946, inplace=True)
# Method 6
pop[(pop['Log GDP per capita'].isna())][(pop['Country name'])=='Somalia'].mask(pop['Log GDP per capita']==np.nan, 7.946, inplace=True)
# Method 7
pop.loc([(pop['Country name']=='Somalia')]['Log GDP per capita'])=7.946
```

How can I improve that?

[Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/zzettrkalpakbal/world-happiness-eda-classic-statistic-with-python)

Comment: Chained access/assignment should be avoided, please see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy.

Comment: (and thanking amounts to accepting/upvoting an answer here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.loc`:

```
mask = pop['Log GDP per capita'].isna() & pop['Country name'].eq('Somalia')
pop.loc[mask, 'Log GDP per capita'] = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will try to replace Nan values per column

[Replace NaN values with specific value per column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967949/replace-nan-values-with-specific-value-per-column)

Or study id you need this Nan Values in your dataframe

Comment: Interestingly, this code worked; 
`pop['Log GDP per capita'].loc[1559:1562].replace(np.nan,7.946,inplace=True)`

But, I think must be an easier way for this.

Comment: Links can eventually lead to a website that no longer exists. It's best to summarize the information on Stack Overflow after which a citation is optional.